# What does "network" mean in the /etc/network/interfaces file?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, alias

In Linux, to define aliases, we have to modify `/etc/network/interfaces`..

Something like this:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.60
netmask 255.255.255.0
network x.x.x.x
broadcast x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
```

What does `network` mean here?

Answer (score 6):

For your case, network is `192.168.1.0`, which means your ip address is in the network range, 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255

You can always get your network base address easily by doing `ip & mask`, where `&` is logical AND.

Comment: i need to set my alias ip as 10.192.161.95 and gateway as 10.192.161.2 what should be my netmask and network? I want to access all 10.X.X.X ips through this gateway.

Comment: your netmask should be `255.0.0.0` and network would be `10.0.0.0`, and your gateway server/router should also be set as netmask `255.0.0.0`